tikzpicture - How to overlay a matrix of images with text
I want to create an A4 template with 2 columns and 5 rows for name tags, each measuring 105 x 55 mm, with a background image of the same size (105 x 55 mm).
I encounter two major issues:

I am unable to overlay any text on the background image.
I would like the width to span (almost) the entire page width of 210
mm (2x105 mm) and be centered so that the verso matches the recto.
For the moment, I have a wider margin on the left side.

Additionally, I need to ensure that the PDF has sufficient resolution when I go to the print shop. My background image is 105 x 55 mm with a resolution of 450 dpi (1860 x 974 pixels). Is it sufficient to use \includegraphics as it is, or should I specify in my *.tex file that I want a higher resolution (e.g., to avoid being limited to 72 dpi)?
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % Option A4 pape:r to ensure the size is A4 210x297 mm
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}%
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\noindent % -> Remove left margin
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={scale=1,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt]{
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
  };
 % Overlay text on each name tag
      \node[anchor=south west, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm] at (0,0) {Jane Smith};
      \node[anchor=south west, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm] at (0,1) {Michael Johnson};
      \node[anchor=south west, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm] at (0,2) {Emily Davis};
      \node[anchor=south west, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm] at (0,3) {Robert Brown};
      \node[anchor=south west, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm] at (0,4) {Linda Wilson};
      \node[anchor=south west, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm] at (1,0) {David Miller};
      \node[anchor=south west, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm] at (1,1) {Sarah Moore};
      \node[anchor=south west, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm] at (1,2) {James Taylor};
      \node[anchor=south west, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm] at (1,3) {Laura Anderson};
      \node[anchor=south west, xshift=10mm, yshift=10mm] at (1,4) {Daniel Thomas};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The result should look like similar to this:


Please convert your example into a minimal working example. For images you can, e.g., use the images of package mwe and scale them using options width and height. However, you have to setup the paper size (e.g. option a4paper), eliminate the paragraph indent (e.g. using \noindent) etc. So you could reduce the question to the single question: How to overlay the images inside the matrix with text.

@cabohah I'll implement your comments. (I didn't know that it is possible to have a MVE with images). I already changed the title of my question, and I will comment inside the MWE when I managed to answer all the side-questions in order not to "polute" the real question.

(comment only, because I don't have the ability to check my work) Rather than setting up the page like you have, you can look into the 'ticket' package, which is designed to create a bunch of blocks (identical or not) on a page.

We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

@cabohah: I removed the answer in the original post and created my own answer. Thank you for your support.

The default paper size of article is letterpaper, which is slightly wider than 210mm. To center on it, you can use \centering as usual. This also eliminates the paragraph indent before the tikzpicture.
And don't forget to eliminate not only the inner and outer separation of the nodes, but also of the matrix.
To refer to the nodes of the matrix, you should name the matrix. Then you can use name-1-1, name-1-2, etc. to write at the positions of the nodes, e.g.:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}%
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix(image)% <-- name added
    [matrix of nodes,nodes={scale=1,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
  };
 % Overlay text on each business card using the name of the matrix
  \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
    \foreach \j in {1,2} {
      \node[red,font=\bfseries\Huge] at (image-\i-\j) {John Doe};
    }
  }
 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


But maybe you want to use A4 paper, so you should also add a4paper as an option to article:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}%
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(image)% <-- name added
  [matrix of nodes,nodes={scale=1,inner sep=0pt,outer
   sep=0pt},column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
 \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}\\ 
  };
 % Overlay text on each business card => this does not work
  \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
    \foreach \j in {1,2} {
      \edef\imagename{image-\i-\j}
      \node[red,font=\bfseries\Huge] at (image-\i-\j) {John Doe};
    }
  }
 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thank you very much. I will add an optimized implementation of your solution, once it is ready.

Here is a working solution for me based on @cabohah answer:
% Document class:
% - extarticle to increase the size of fonts
% - a4paper option to ensure the size is A4 210x297 mm
\documentclass[a4paper, 17pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}% <-- Use of system font
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}%
\setmainfont{Kunstler Script} %<-- MS Windows system font
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\addimg}{\includegraphics[width=105mm,height=55mm]{example-image}}

%#1 : x-coordinate of the matrix
%#2 : y-coordinate of the matrix
%#3 : First name
%#4 : Last name
\newcommand{\addnametwolines}[4]{%
  \edef\imagename{image-#1-#2}
  \node[xshift=-30pt, font=\Huge, align=center] at (image-#1-#2){
    \begin{minipage}[c]{73mm}
      \centering%
      #3\\
      #4
    \end{minipage}
  };
}

\begin{document}
  \centering% <-- Ensure centering for matching recto & verso
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(image)% <-- name added to refer to it
    [matrix of nodes,nodes={scale=1,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{
      \addimg & \addimg \\ 
      \addimg & \addimg \\ 
      \addimg & \addimg \\ 
      \addimg & \addimg \\ 
      \addimg & \addimg \\ 
    }; 
    \addnametwolines{1}{1}{Jane}{Smith}
    \addnametwolines{1}{2}{Michael}{Johnson}
    \addnametwolines{2}{1}{Emily}{Davis}
    \addnametwolines{2}{2}{Robert}{Brown}
    \addnametwolines{3}{1}{Linda}{Wilson}
    \addnametwolines{3}{2}{David}{Miller}
    \addnametwolines{4}{1}{Sarah}{Moore}
    \addnametwolines{4}{2}{James}{Taylor}
    \addnametwolines{5}{1}{Laura}{Anderson}
    \addnametwolines{5}{2}{Daniel}{Thomas}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

